# "Stretch" Shader on Cube as cubemap (Three.js)

Tags: three.js, shader

Salu.

Got an interesting [shader from shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/tdSXzD) (all licenses to authors).

I managed to convert the shadertoy into ThreeJS "friendly" shader. However, it does apply on each side of the cube as separate image. Aiming to make a customisable shader similar to Three.js [Sky and Sun shader](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_shaders_sky.html).

Done my homework about shader "stretching" on cubes, yet no results (weird things happening). Could you explain/help achieving proper cubemap?

Jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/mrNull/f54uyevk

```
//vertex-shader
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() {
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    vUv = uv;
 }
```

Tried: replace vUv with gl_Position, mvPosition - got singleColoredCube.